# Which is more space efficient, multiple colums or multple rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

Suppose if i have a table A with 100 columns of same data type and 100 rows.

Table B with 2 columns and 5000 rows of same data type of above table columns.

Which table takes more disk space to store & which is more efficient?

Comment: Do mean different levels of normalisation; so the first table has say id., value1, value2, value3, value4, ... while the second has id, value_num, value? That's the only way I can think you could have the same data represented both ways. Effectively one is a pivot of the other. Space should be a secondary consideration (at best) over functionality, normalisation, etc.

Comment: You do not provide enough information to give a reasonable answer to the question.  When you say more "memory" do you mean RAM or disk?  What does "efficiency" mean?  What are the data types, because the answer might depend on the types.  In all likelihood, the differences between two such small tables would be irrelevant in practice.

Comment: My question is which table takes more disk space to store data. I see most of the people commenting the design is not good. I just need to know which table takes more disk space.

Comment: @uhs _Why_ do you need to know which table takes more disk space? What is your end-goal? I can just generally say that correctly modeling the database is usually more important than space, but it's hard to say more with the information you supplied so far. Please edit your question to include more information and we may consider reopening it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real answer here is... it depends.

Oracle stores its data in "data blocks", which are stored in "Extents" which are stored in "Segments" which make up the "Tablespace". [See here.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/logical.htm)

A data block is much like a block used to store data for the operating system. In fact, an Oracle data block should be specified in multiples of the operating system's blocks so there isn't unnecessary I/O overhead.

A data block is split into 5 chunks:

1. **The Header** - Which has information about the block
2. **The Table Directory** - Tells oracle that this block contains info about whatever table it is storing data for
3. **Row Directory** - The portion of the block that stores information about the rows in the block like addresses.
4. **Row data** - The meat and potatoes of the block where the row data is stored.  Keeping in mind that Rows can span blocks.
5. **Free space** - This is the middle of the bingo board and you don't have to actually put your chip here.

So the two important parts of Oracle data storage, for this question, in it's data blocks are the Row Data and the Row Directory (And to some extend, the Free Space).

In your first table you have very large rows, but fewer of them. This would suggest a smaller row directory (unless it spans multiple blocks because of the size of the rows, in which case it would be Rows*Blocks-Necessary-To-Store-Them). In your second table you have more rows, which would suggest a larger row directory than the first table.

I believe that a row directory entry is two bytes. It describes the offset in bytes from the start of the block where the row data can be found. If your data types for your two columns in second table are `TINYINT()` then your rows would be 2 bytes as well. In effect, you have more rows, so your directory here is as big as your data. It's datasize*2, which will cause you to store more data for this table.

The other gotcha here is that data stored in the row directory of a block is not deleted when the row is deleted. The header that contains the row directory in the block is only reused when a new insert comes along that needs the space.

Also, every block has it's free space that it keeps for storing more rows and header information, as well as holding transaction entries (see the link above for that).

At any rate, it's unlikely that your row directory in a given block would be larger than your row data, and even then Oracle may be holding onto free space in the block that trumps both depending on the size of the table and how often it's accessed and whether oracle is automatically managing free space for you, or your managing manually (does anyone do that?).

Also, if you toss an index on either of these tables, you'll change the stats all around anyway. Indexes are stored like tables, and they have their own Segments, extents, and blocks.

In the end, your best bet is to not worry too much about the blocks and whatnot (after all, storage is cheap) instead:

1. Define appropriate field types for your data. Don't store boolean values in a CHAR(100), for instance.
2. Define your indexes wisely. Don't add an index just to be sure. Make good decisions when your tuning.
3. Design your schema for your end user's needs. Is this a reporting database? In that case, shoot for denormalized pre-aggregated data to keep reads fast. Try to keep down the number of joins a user needs to get at their result set.
4. Focus on cutting CPU and I/O requirements based on the queries that will come through for the schema you have created. Storage is cheap, CPU and I/O aren't, and your end user isn't going to give a rats ass about how many hard drives (or ram if it's in-memory) you needed to cram into your box. They are going to care about how quick the application reads and writes.

p.s.  Forgive me if I misrepresented anything here. Logical database storage is complicated stuff and I don't deal much with Oracle so I may be missing a piece to the puzzle, but the overall gist is the same. There is the actual data you store, and then there is the metadata for that data. It's unlikely that the metadata will trump, in size, the data itself, but given the right circumstances, it's possible (especially with indexing figured in). And, in the end, don't worry to much about it anyway. Focus on the needs of the end user/application in designing your schema. The end user will balk a hell of a lot more than your box.

Comment: I'm even more impressed that your profile doesn't mention Oracle.

Comment: Maybe I should stick it on there. I kind of have a thing for reading through data storage documentation. It's interesting to see what a mature product like Oracle (or a mature FS like Ext3) does to squeeze out I/O efficiencies and maintain data integrity.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very clear.

Answer (score 6):

Either a table has 2 columns or 100. You would not convert one into the other or you would do something very wrong.

A product table may have 100 columns (item number, description, supplier number, material, list price, actual price ...). How would you make this a two column table? A key-value table? A very bad idea.

A country table may have 2 columns (iso code and name). How would you make this a 100-columns table? By having columns usa_name, usa_code, germany_name, germany_code, ...? An even worse idea.

So: The question is out of question :-) There is nothing to decide between.

Comment: I am just asking which table takes more disk space to store. Doesn't matter whether table design is worst or good.

Comment: And I am saying this question doesn't make much sense. You could also ask whether storing an image or a sound clip takes more space on disk; they are different things. So is a table with 2 or 100 columns; they are meant to store different data; so why ask at all? The answer would probably not help you in anything. You won't say "Ah, a country table is smaller than a product table? Then I'd better store countries than products.", right?

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency is a nebulous concept, and depends on what you are measuring. If you are having to jump through hoops extracting data that is poorly indexed (or requires function-based indexes) that were implemented because disk space was deemed more important than proper design, then I'd say that you will wind up with a far less efficient app from both a data retrieval standpoint, not to mention having to deal with code complexity implemented to try and overcome poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that each column has to store some meta data, I'm guessing that table B might be more space efficient, since the size of your actual data is constant and equal in both cases.

Comment: Usually every record in a DBMS has some overhead, so table B might need more bytes to store the same data

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks a lot man. 

Answer (score 0):

In terms of **memory** I think it depends on type of data (images, videos, int, varchar...etc) stored in the tables. (assuming you do not mean that both tables contains the same data as I do not see how you'd change the columns into rows)

In terms of **efficiency** and I hope I am right if I say that table B is more efficient as indexing 2 columns is easier that indexing 5 therefore data can be retrieved easier in any way possible compared to a table with 5 columns where some kind of query might take longer time.